# What database should I use for a location tracking android application?

Tags: android, java, postgresql, sqlite, firebase

So I want to develop an online mobile application using android studio and java. A client mobile application that will send its location to the admin mobile application, so it will be using GPS. what is the best database to use here? I am currently choosing between firebase, postgresql and sqlite?

Comment: Do you want to run the database as part of an app on the Android inside the app or as a server on the internet?

Comment: it would be as a server on the internet, and also I want the database to be updated realtime, the faster the better

Comment: So when there's no network connection (e.g. tracking/hiking in the mountains), the app will be useless? I'd rather put it locally and use SQLite, which is well established with Android apps – then have the sync optional. And I'd avoid stuff that binds me to a specific provider – especially if that provider already has a history tracking its users (and not just restricted to location). If your app shall be FOSS, dependencies like Firebase would massively taint it (essentially it would no longer be FOSS as Firebase is not).

Comment: PostgreSQL in combination with PostGIS is as far as I know a very common combination for a database with geo and location data. And for temporary local storage in the app (for offline times) SQLite is also common on Android.

Comment: so the application is for a school project and it would be intended to be use on emergency times only, so kind of like 911 but with geolocation tracking. based on you comments I wanted to use postgres and postgis but I cant seem to find tutorials on it. Thank you for you comments